# How to replace all instances of a number throughout my entire cell

Tags: replacement

I have a cell where for several instances throughout I label certain functions, strings, and ranges using a similar pattern so as to follow through with integration calculations, list forming, and plotting.

All of the labels feature a similar format that indicate a certain depth and layer, such as Si1000nm where I just add whatever I want at the label ( Si1000nmlist, Si1000nmAbsorbtion, etc.)

I have to repeat across many different depths, however when I copy over the code format and to a new cell and use find next and replace, it does not change a single thing.

I am wondering if there is any built in function that allows me to replace all instances of a distance of the form #nm across all the entire cell. I know that I can use /. and StringReplace for expressions and strings respectively, however would just like to encapsulate the entire cell, replace all instances of a distance, and then continue on with performing a calculation regardless of whether the distance is present in a string, expression, etc.

Comment: Why not build a function that takes terms like Si1000 as an argument, and then apply it with Si1001 and Si1002 when needed? Copy and pasting followed by replacement is unlikely to be the easiest approach.

Comment: Whenever you're manipulating stuff in a `Cell` you'll need to understand how `NotebookWrite` and friends work and about the "box language". Your basic format will look like `NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], NotebookRead@EvaluationCell[]/.s_String:>(StringReplace[s,___])]`.